# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: BenefitResponseDto -> BenefitResponse

Tags: c#, .net

I made a BenefitProfile for made the autoMapper between BenefitResponseDto and BenefitResponse

```
public class BenefitResponseDto : BaseResponseDto
    {
        public BenefitDetailsResponseDto Retorno { get; set; }
    }

public class BenefitDetailsResponseDto
    {
        public BenefitInformationDto Dados { get; set; }
    }

public class BenefitInformationDto
    {
        public IEnumerable<BenefitDto> Beneficio { get; set; }
        public SessionDto DadosConsulta { get; set; }
    }

public class BenefitResponse
    {
        public List<Benefit> Benefit { get; set; }
    }
```

And my BenefitProfile is like there

```
public class BenefitProfile : Profile
    {
        public BenefitProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<BenefitResponseDto, BenefitResponse>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Benefit, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Retorno.Dados.Beneficio));

            CreateMap<BenefitInformationDto, BenefitResponse>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Benefit, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Beneficio));

            CreateMap<BenefitDetailsResponseDto, BenefitInformationDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DadosConsulta, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dados));

            CreateMap<BenefitDto, Benefit>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DescriptionPromotion, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DescricaoPromocao))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PromotionName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NomePromocao))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.VoucherCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CodigoVoucher))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.VoucherStartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DataInicioVoucher))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.VoucherEndDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DataFimVoucher))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.VoucherUseDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DataUtilizacaoVoucher))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NameStoreVoucher, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NomeLojaVoucher))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PointsSituation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SituacaoPontos))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.QuantityPoints, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DataInclusao))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DataAtualizacao))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CodeDirectMail, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CodigoMalaDireta))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IdPromotionCea, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IdPromocaoCea))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DescriptionBenefit, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DescricaoBeneficio))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ConditionUseBenefit, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CondicaoUsoBeneficio))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ChannelVoucherUse, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CanalUsoVoucher));

            CreateMap<IEnumerable<BenefitDto>, List<Benefit>>().ConvertUsing<ListConverter<BenefitDto, Benefit>>();
        }
    }

    public class ListConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<TSource>, List<TDestination>>
    {
        public List<TDestination> Convert(IEnumerable<TSource> source, List<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, List<TDestination>>(source);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to test the mapper, i receiving the error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
BenefitResponseDto -> BenefitResponse
```

I made a Profile for the mapper and in my Service I called an instance of mapper

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core